# Is it possible to customize drawer symbol in appbar on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I need to stack a circle behind of the drawer symbol on the appbar but it seems like there is no way to of styling by placing a circle beneath so that it looks like :
[image of imagined appbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsgcj.png)

Another alternate is that I do a symbol and without calling the drawer or appbar function from flutter which is what I am currently doing but I have no idea how to call a drawer from an icon. [image of what I have done and how I can call a drawer from using an icon and a container stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6o7I.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, overriding the default `leading` with your own custom component and wrapping it in an `InkWell` to handle the opening of the drawer.

To create a border instead of coloring the whole circle, set the `color` to `Colors.transparent` and add a `border` to your `BoxDecoration`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My appbar'),
        leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
          child: Container(
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            decoration: const  BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.menu,
            ),
          ),
        ), 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a custom "appbar" that I made but I am facing the problem of how do I call on the drawable function without using the build in one from flutter.